# Adding entity in the domain service insert method

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-ria-services, domainservices

I have two entities, `Parent` and `Child`, at the client side i create `Parent` and then call `context.submitChanges`

At the server side in the `InsertParent(Parent parent)` i do:

```
InsertParent(Parent parent)
{
   Child child = this.ObjectContext.Childs.CreateObject();
   parent.child = child;

   if ((parent.EntityState != EntityState.Detached))
   {
     this.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(parent, EntityState.Added);
   }
   else
   {
    this.ObjectContext.Parents.AddObject(parent);
   }
}
```

Now i'm having two problems.

Before the if else, `Parent.id` is 0 and after its still 0 but in the database its populated.

The other one is, `Child` gets saved but `Child.ParentId` is 0.

I'm not understanding why.

Whats the correct way to achieve this behaviour? should i call `SaveChanges()` on the context directly?

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure the StoreGeneratedPattern property on Parent.Id in your edmx is set to Identity. That should make sure it gets updated with the new value on inserts.

I'd also wrap this in a transaction so you can add your child after the parent id is set.

```
using(var scope = new TransactionScope()){
    ObjectContext.Parents.AddObject(parent);
    ObjectContext.SaveChanges(); //parent.id assigned
    parent.child = ObjectContext.Child.CreateObject();
    ObjectContext.SaveChanges();
    scope.Complete(); // commit transaction
}
```

Comment: EntityFramework allows you to add both at the same time and you don't even need to use a transaction for that. But the Identity part of your answer is correct and i forget about it.

Comment: I might be wrong for the current version of EF, but I believe that if your are using POCO entities and they are not configured for Change Tracking then you do need to wrap with a transaction.  However, you are correct that if you are just using default, EF generated, entities then you should not need the transaction and one `SaveChanges` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should use the *SaveChanges()* because that's what persist your data into the Database.

[Very Easy Example](http://blog.aggregatedintelligence.com/2010/05/entity-framework-inserting-objects-with.html)

You also need to check the parents.Id column and childs Id column that they are set as identity and as primary keys, and the relations between the two tables.

Comment: Could you elaborate? if i call SaveChanges() before parent is added, child.ParentID will be 0?

Comment: If you call SaveChanges before you add the parent it won't do anything.

Comment: The very easy example shows you how to add an object and it's child to the database.